# React-native-meteor package subscription handle not ready

Tags: javascript, meteor, react-native, ddp

I'm trying to combine react-native and meteor using the react-native-meteor package. Meteor successfully publishes a 'dos' collection, which I have been able to subscribe to on the web client. However, after following the documentation of the react-native-meteor package (using createContainer) I am unable to subscribe; the handle is 'never ready'. When using the autopublish package from Meteor the data does load.

Versions

```
Meteor 1.3.4.1

react-native: 0.28.0

react-native-meteor: 1.0.0-rc14
```

index.ios.js

```
// @flow
'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS,
  StatusBar,
  Text,
} from 'react-native'
import Meteor, {
  createContainer,
  MeteorListView,
 } from 'react-native-meteor'

Meteor.connect('ws://localhost:3000/websocket')

import GeoLocation from './app/GeoLocation'
import ConnectionInfoSubscription from './app/NetInfo'
import GridLayout from './app/GridLayout'

class DoCHANGE_0 extends Component {

  renderRow(Do){
    return(
      <Text>{Do.joke}</Text>
    )
  }

  render() {

    const { doList, } = this.props

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle="light-content"
        />
      <NavigatorIOS
        style = {styles.container}
        barTintColor='#556270'
        titleTextColor='#fff'
        tintColor='#fff'
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'DoCHANGE',
          component: GridLayout
        }}/>

        {!doList && <Text>Not ready with subscription</Text>}
        <MeteorListView
        collection="dos"
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        />

      </View>
    )
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
  }
});

export default createContainer(params=>{
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('dos')
  return {
    doList: handle.ready(),
  };
}, DoCHANGE_0)

AppRegistry.registerComponent('DoCHANGE_0', () => DoCHANGE_0);
```

I have found similar examples but they often don't utilise the react-native-meteor package but use the ddpclient package instead. Am I missing something obvious here? Any insights is much appreciated!

Edit:

(Meteor) /server/publish.js

```
 Meteor.publish("dos", function() {
   //console.log(Dos.find().fetch())
   return Dos.find();
 })
```

(Meteor) /both/collections.js

```
Dos = new Mongo.Collection('dos');
```

Screenshot when using autopublish from Meteor. doList handle is still not ready. But the MeteorList gets populated correctly.

[Screenshot iOS autopublish on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3tJ6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to newer versions of react-native, meteor, and react-native-meteor but that didn't solve the issue. However, when renaming the renderRow function to renderItem it started working.

```
renderRow={this.renderRow}

renderRow={this.renderItem}
```

Comment: This can't be the cause of problem!

Comment: Are you sure that your Meteor.publish for dos collection is running on server?

Answer (score 0):

You only included client side code in your question, but it sounds like you are missing the [Meteor.publish()](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html) call on the server, if it works using autopublish but not without it!

Comment: I thought that it wasn't necessary to include since it is possible to subscribe on the web client to the collection. The server has the Dos = new Mongo.Collection('dos) in a folder (outside server/client) and a basic Meteor.publish("dos", function() { return Dos.find()}) in a publish.js underneath the server folder.. Nothing special here.. But I'll add it to the post.

Comment: You can subscribe to an unpublished collection. You just won't get any data.

Comment: Using MeteorToys I can see the populated collection. So that's why I'm assuming the error to be within the RN code..

Comment: Ok, that's a significant info. But then why would autopublish make it work? Should not change anything client side. Are you dependent on some other collection which you don't have a publish for?

Comment: No, the only collection I have is 'dos' which is populated with some text. The only thing I can imagine is an issue with the MeteorList. The 'doList' handle is never ready. So when autopublish is on, I will see the doList still as false (and it shows 'Not ready with subscription') but the content from the collection is pushed underneath. In the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-meteor example they show subscribing to a 'todos' and 'settings' collection, one uses a handle whereas the other does not. I'm assuming that using a handle is best in this situation.

Comment: Added a screenshot for clarification

Comment: Hmm... One thing I notice: You are returning handle.ready() from createContainer. That's *not* in the list of things that are reactive, according to the react-native-meteor readme. The handle itself (the return from Meter.subscribe()) is, however. So can it be that you are checking .ready() only once, and there is no observer attached to that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, following the initial example in the docs, the handle.ready() only takes care of the 'loading/not available yet' message. The MeteorViewList does the actual loading of data; make sense that with autopublish it does work. I also tried with another return value that is reactive (Meteor.collection....) with no luck. No clue where to look for an answer/solution.

Comment: Make sure publish.js is imported in server/main.js so that publish function runs on server!